Read The Docs (Sphinx) PDF download functionality
Is there a known method to modify the default PDF download settings for Read The Docs?
Specifically I'm interested in:

Custom styling
Ability to download a single article/page/file (while retaining the complete manual download"

I have not explored this beyond a cursory look, I'm unsure where to start.

Since you are using Sphinx to produce the PDF output, you should follow their "LaTeX customization" guide for custom styling.
Besides, if you want to build different PDF files with different sections, you should use latex_documents config.
